# Agregarle un 0 a la izquierda a un número entero en Python

Tags: python

Hola queridos amigos de Stack Over Flow si tengo la variable numero = 125, ¿Cómo podría agregarle ceros a la izquierda? de tal forma que me quede un float asi numero = 0.125.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Sirve hacer: `numero / 1000`, o `float("0."+str(numero))`, o `float(f'0.{numero}')`?

Answer (score 1):

si sabes cuantos cuantos dígitos tiene la variable , es solamente dividir el número por un múltiplo de 10 de acuerdo al largo del número la cantidad de ceros, ej:

125 / 1000 = 0.125

ahora bien supongamos que puede ser un número que no conoces su largo, bueno,  es lo mismo solo que averiguando el largo:

```
entero = 33125
flotante = entero / (10**len(f"{entero}")) 
print(flotante)
```